# Git rebase undos all changes/commits to local branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I made some local changes and then committed them (let's call this `commit A`). I then made and committed some more small changes (`commit B`), and since I didn't want to clutter up my commit history with a bunch of small changes, I tried to squash `commit B` into `commit A`. Basically I wanted the remote's `commit A` to represent what I had in my local immediately after making `commit B`.

I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, and squashed `commit B` into `commit A`.

This then reverted the local branch to what it was before BOTH A and B. I managed to revert this using `git rebase --abort`, but I am confused as to why this happened, especially as I have used `git rebase -i HEAD~N` in the past to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to `git reset HEAD~2 —soft` and commit again.

As to why your commits were lost, I’m not sure, normally this should work if you use the interactive rebase to squash commit B into A:

```
s b1cf5f0ffc <COMMIT B>
pick e24a3f5975 <COMMIT A>
pick 8785438d31 ...
```

Comment: I've already pushed the commits and merged them via a merge request, if I go `git reset HEAD~2 -soft` how do I make sure the squash gets propagated to the remote as well?

Comment: The only way to squash commits which are already pushed to remote is by overwriting with a forced push `git push -f`

Comment: `git reset HEAD~2 -soft` then `git status` shows several files as being edited (all the files that commits A and B changed). `git diff` shows no changes and the files' content is unchanged. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Yes that’s normal. You will see the changes with `git diff —staged`